# Passing objects using didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

How do I pass between objects from uitableviews to my detail views? I've set up a conditional push, as you can see in my method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Budget * tempBudget = [self.budgetPlan.budgets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *targetViewControllerIdentifier = nil;
    if (tempBudget.hasBeenInitialized != true) {
        targetViewControllerIdentifier = @"budgetInitializerView";
        UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:targetViewControllerIdentifier];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

        // how do I pass the tempBudget to the pushed view?


    } else {
        targetViewControllerIdentifier = @"budgetDetailsView";
        UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:targetViewControllerIdentifier];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

        // how do I pass the tempBudget to the pushed view?

    }
}
```

I'm having trouble with the `UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:targetViewControllerIdentifier];`

Usually, I just set
    vc.budget = tempbudget as the answer below suggests, but it does not seem to understand the budget property.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "does not seem to understand the budget property"? Compiler warning? Crash? Nothing displayed on the new view?

Comment: Nothing is displayed in the new view. It does not seem to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a `BaseViewController` that has a `@property` of type of your object and send your object in that way.

```
// In your .h
BaseViewController : UIViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) Budget *budget;

//In your .m
@synthesize budget;
```

Also, you can move this line out of your if/else statement, since it's the same thing:

```
vc.budget = tempBudget;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

set your budget property right before you push your view controller

Comment: It does not seem to be passing the data still for some reason if I do vc.Budget = tempBudget.

Comment: Also, I can't move the vc.budget = tempBudget as it is a local variable.

Comment: If you have a property created in Class you most certainly can pass a local variable to it.

Comment: I meant that I couldn't exclude the vc.budget = tempBudget from the if/then scope.